# Scroll bar is not available for DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have loaded the DataGrid in to the Items Control, I have query on while the content of the DataGrid exceeds from the screen size the scroll bar is not shown automatically inside the container for scrolling purpose. I have noticed that the issue occurs only when set the height of the container as Auto. If i set the height as star means its working fine as expected manner. I hope this may state my struggling clearly could you please share you suggestion on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ScrollViewers` and virtualization don't work when setting the `Height` of the parent `Panel` to `Auto` because this basically means that the `ScrollViewer` gets an infinite or unknown height and there is no way to tell when to actually display the scroll bars.

A `ScrollViewer` needs some kind of size contraint to be able to work properly and that's why you should either set the `Height` to a fixed value or to `*` to make it occupy all available space. `Height=Auto` won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion on this.